# How to store access token of OAuth1.0a to use for all time requests to protected API? I'm using using Scribe Library

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, magento-1.8, scribe, oauth-1.0a

I'm using the [Scribe Library](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/wiki/getting-started) to implement OAuth1.0a and somehow i got the AccessToken from Magento Service Provider. But my question is how to store and use the AccessToken for the further more requests i make using the `service.signRequest(accessToken, request);`to access the Magento OAuth1.0a REST api call?

`Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, v);`

```
          Assume: Token accessToken = xxxxxxxxxx;
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, REST_API_URL);
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
```

How to **store the accessToken in the Android application** for lifetime access securely to access the **Magento REST api url**? I saved it in String variable but i can't use that in

```
           service.signRequest("can't use the string value here", request);
```

So, how to store and use the **accessToken**

If you need more clarification on this question please leave a comment. Let me explain my question.